# Python: using twittersearch api to get twitter.retweeted.id

Tags: python, api, search, twitter

I am trying to get the id of the original tweet that was retweeted (see docs: http://dev.datasift.com/docs/sources/public-sources/twitter) using the twittersearch api with little result. I want to use twitter search to to specifically get: twitter.retweeted.id

This is my code:

```
import datetime
import csv
import itertools as it

import codecs
tweet_text_id = []
from TwitterSearch import TwitterSearchOrder, TwitterUserOrder, TwitterSearchException, TwitterSearch
try:
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder() 
    tso.set_keywords([""]) 
    tso.set_language('')
    tso.set_include_entities(True) 



    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = "aaa",
        consumer_secret = "bbb",
        access_token = "ccc",
        access_token_secret = "dddd"
     )

    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
            tweet_text_id.append({'id':tweet['id'], 'text': tweet['text'].encode('utf8'), 'retweeted' : tweet ['retweeted']['id']})

    for i in tweet_text_id:
         print(i)


except TwitterSearchException as e: 
    print(e)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I've also tried:

```
tweet_text_id.append({'id':tweet['id'], 'text': tweet['text'].encode('utf8'), 'retweeted' : tweet['retweeted'_'id']})
```

and:

```
tweet_text_id.append({'id':tweet['id'], 'text': tweet['text'].encode('utf8'), 'retweeted' : retweeted['id']})
```

Is there anyway to get this via twittersearch? if not: anyone with experience on how to retrieve it via twython?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

found it :

it should be:

```
 for retweeted in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        tweet_text_id.append({'retweeted' : retweeted['id']})
```

doing this:

```
for retweeted, tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
tweet_text_id.append({'id':tweet['id'], 'text': tweet['text'].encode('utf8'), 'retweeted' : tweet ['retweeted']['id']})
```

results in this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So you just have to write a seperate loop for tweet